# rails - manipulate datetime data before_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, datetime, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: Schedule and Task.  Task belongs_to Schedule and Schedule has_many tasks.  The form for tasks is a nested form of Schedule.  I am trying to write either controller code or a model method that will take a user inputted datetime (called :time_frame) for task, and if that datetime has already occurred (is in the past), will spit out a notice and redirect.  I have tried doing this several ways, but none of them worked.  I tried writing this controller code for schedules#update:

```
schedule_params[:tasks_attributes].each do |task|
    if task[:time_frame] < DateTime.now
         render 'update', :notice => 'You must pick a future time.'
    end 
end
```

And here is schedule_params:

```
def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:emp_accepts, 
        tasks_attributes: [:title, :content, :_destroy, :time_frame, 
        :complete_time])    
end
```

but i was returned the error:

```
no implicit conversion of symbol to integer
```

I tried writing a model method like this in the Schedule model:

```
before_update :compare_datetimes

def compare_datetimes
    puts 'before task is found'
    self.tasks.each do |task|
        puts 'here is the task'
        if task.time_frame < DateTime.now
            puts 'It is in the past'
        end
    end
end
```

'before task is found' is put to the server, but neither of the other two puts are being executed.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a validation to the task model to do the check on the time_frame before you save it:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :time_frame, presence: true # if you require time_frame to always be present
  validate :datetime_in_future

  private

  def datetime_in_future
    # if time_frame is optional, check its presence before comparing
    if !self.time_frame.blank? && self.time_frame < DateTime.now
      errors.add :time_frame, 'must be a future time.'
    end
  end
end
```

This should invalidate your associations and, therefore, the schedule, when you save or update it.

About your controller: The reason that didn't work is that you didnt parse the time_frame before comparing it to the datetime, you should do this:

```
if DateTime.parse(task[:time_frame]) < DateTime.now
  # code here ...
```

That's because the controller sees the time_frame value in its raw string form. When you assign it to your task activerecord will cast it to the data type of the column which is datetime (i assume you set it that way in the migration).

**Update:**
Regarding the controller error where you get `no implicit conversion of symbol to integer` The `tasks_attributes` is an indexed hash so you need to iterate over it like this:

```
schedule_params[:tasks_attributes].each_pair do |index, task|
    if task[:time_frame] < DateTime.now
         render 'update', :notice => 'You must pick a future time.'
    end 
end
```

But of course, the validation on task model is the better way to solve this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the validate method but it returns the error 'undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass' if time_Frame is blank

Comment: if you require the time_frame to always be present add a presence validator before the datetime_in_future validator. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: Thanks.  With regards to the controller, it is still returning the same no implicit conversion of symbol to string error?

Comment: I'l update my answer with that solution, I missed something before.